# How to change collection of form field depending on a previous answer using Ruby on Rails and Simple Form gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project and using the Simple Form gem for my forms. I have a form where I need to change the collection of a select field based on the user's previous answer to another field.

For example, if the user selects "Category A" in the first field, the second field should show options only related to "Category A" and if the user selects "Category B", the second field should show options only related to "Category B".

How can I achieve this functionality using Ruby on Rails and Simple Form gem?

```
<% if @property.ubicacion == 'Panama' %>
   <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.input :localizacion,  collection: ['Costa del Este' ] %></div>
<% elsif @property.ubicacion == 'Playas'%>
   <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.input :localizacion,  collection: ['Corronado' ] %></div>
<% else %>
   <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.input :localizacion,  collection: ['' ] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a really common question and it's off-topic as its far too broad and would require a lengthy tutorial or even a book as an answer. To update the UI as the user clicks  on something you need to use JavaScript - there are tons of tutorials and libraries for this purpose. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/